# INSERT INTO in IB Expert

Tags: sql, firebird, ibexpert

I have thousands of lines that look like this:

```sql
insert into TABLE (name) values ('name_1');
insert into TABLE (name) values ('name_2');
...
insert into TABLE (name) values ('name_10000');
```

Executing them one by one works just fine. But when I want to run two or more at once it will always return error at 2nd line:

```
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 2, column 1.
insert.
```

Any clues how to fix it? Removing `;` changes nothing.

Comment: have you tried using `EXECUTE BLOCK`

Comment: @JaimeDrq yes, and now it returns `Unexpected end of command`. But at least not at line 2, but at 146.

Comment: This means it is trying execute everything as if it is a single statement. You need to execute this as a script so IB Expert will execute the individual statement (however, I don't know IB Expert to say how to do that). Firebird itself can only execute individual statements (or statements in a PSQL block like `EXECUTE BLOCK`).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel solved. Need to execute these lines as script. All other ways/combinations will result in error.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for `EXECUTE BLOCK` should be something like this:

```
execute block
as
begin
  insert into TABLE (name) values ('name_1');
  insert into TABLE (name) values ('name_2');
  ...
  insert into TABLE (name) values ('name_10000');
end
```

Comment: @resharper no it does not - https://i.imgur.com/zhzHKyY.png

Answer (score 1):

Execution of several SQL commands at once must be done not in the "SQL Editor" but in the "Script Executive" (Ctrl-F12 instead of F12).

Comment: Now it returns error `Cannot perform operation -- DB is not open.`

Comment: You must choose database connection using combo box in left upper corner of the window.

Comment: It is picked. Maybe it lacks connect statement?

Comment: No. Choosing the connection in the combo box and connect statement are interchangeable. Make sure that chosen connection is opened not just "current" - sometimes it doesn't work. @resharper